# Annotation(stamp) missed after flattened

Tags: pdf, itext, flatten

Annotation(PdfName.STAMP) missed after flattened by itextsharp5.5.13.1.
I have two pdfs. One does work, the other does not work.
Any ideas will be appreciated.

**The code is following**

```
string outFile = inputFile + "_f.pdf";
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFileName))
{
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))

    //pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    //pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.AnnotationFlattening = true;
    //pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;

}
```

Comment: [worked pdf](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AkDpL-6DTpJjjxb6JngAvFAU7fVq?e=rxoBhP) [NOT WORK pdf](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AkDpL-6DTpJjjxU3bIpr5uLxOuMZ?e=LDD7Nk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***The cause*** is a bug in iTextSharp, annotation flattening does not correctly calculate the position for the flattened annotation if its bounding box does not use the origin as lower left corner.

If you look at the code of `PdfStamperImp.FlattenAnnotations(bool)`, you'll quickly realize that the calculations in the `if (app != null)` block only make sense if the bounding box is located at the origin or no scaling is necessary for fitting the appearance bounding box into the annotation rectangle.

(As often the lower left corner of the bounding box is the origin, this does not pop up often.)

***Thus, for flattening*** such annotations you have to use a different method for flattening, e.g. like this:

```cs
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFileName))
{
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
    ImprovedAnnotationFlattening(pdfStamper);
    pdfStamper.Close();
}
```

with these helper methods:

```cs
void ImprovedAnnotationFlattening(PdfStamper pdfStamper)
{
    double[] DEFAULT_MATRIX = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };

    PdfReader reader = pdfStamper.Reader;

    for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; ++page)
    {
        PdfDictionary pageDic = reader.GetPageN(page);
        PdfArray annots = pageDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

        if (annots == null)
            continue;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < annots.Size; ++idx)
        {
            PdfObject annoto = annots.GetDirectObject(idx);
            if (!(annoto is PdfDictionary))
                continue;

            PdfDictionary annDic = (PdfDictionary)annoto;

            PdfNumber ff = annDic.GetAsNumber(PdfName.F);
            int flags = ff != null ? ff.IntValue : 0;
            if ((flags & PdfFormField.FLAGS_PRINT) == 0 || (flags & PdfFormField.FLAGS_HIDDEN) != 0)
                continue;

            PdfObject obj1 = annDic.Get(PdfName.AP);
            if (obj1 == null)
                continue;
            PdfDictionary appDic = obj1 is PdfIndirectReference
                ? (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj1)
                : (PdfDictionary)obj1;
            PdfObject obj = appDic.Get(PdfName.N);
            PdfStream objDict = appDic.GetAsStream(PdfName.N);

            if (objDict != null)
            {
                Rectangle rect = PdfReader.GetNormalizedRectangle(annDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT));
                Rectangle bbox = PdfReader.GetNormalizedRectangle(objDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.BBOX));

                PdfContentByte cb = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(page);
                cb.SetLiteral("Q ");

                PdfArray matrixArray = objDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.MATRIX);
                double[] matrix = matrixArray != null ? matrixArray.AsDoubleArray() : DEFAULT_MATRIX;
                AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform(matrix);

                double[] bboxCorners = { bbox.Left, bbox.Bottom, bbox.Right, bbox.Bottom, bbox.Right, bbox.Top, bbox.Left, bbox.Top };
                transform.Transform(bboxCorners, 0, bboxCorners, 0, 4);
                double minX = Min(bboxCorners, 0, 2);
                double maxX = Max(bboxCorners, 0, 2);
                double minY = Min(bboxCorners, 1, 2);
                double maxY = Max(bboxCorners, 1, 2);

                transform.preConcatenate(AffineTransform.GetTranslateInstance(-minX, -minY));
                transform.preConcatenate(AffineTransform.GetScaleInstance(rect.Width/(maxX-minX), rect.Height/(maxY-minY)));
                transform.preConcatenate(AffineTransform.GetTranslateInstance(rect.Left, rect.Bottom));

                transform.GetMatrix(matrix);

                cb.AddFormXObj(objDict, GenerateName(), matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3], matrix[4], matrix[5]);

                cb.SetLiteral("q ");

                annots.Remove(idx);
                --idx;
            }
        }
    }
}

double Min(double[] array, int start, int step)
{
    double result = array[start];

    for (int i = start + step; i < array.Length; i+=step)
    {
        result = Math.Min(result, array[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

double Max(double[] array, int start, int step)
{
    double result = array[start];

    for (int i = start + step; i < array.Length; i += step)
    {
        result = Math.Max(result, array[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

PdfName GenerateName()
{
    PdfName name = new PdfName("XXX" + formXObjectsCounter);
    ++formXObjectsCounter;
    return name;
}

int formXObjectsCounter = 4711;
```

**Beware:** I just wrote these methods (copying as much as possible from the original flattening code) and only tested with your example files. Some border conditions might still have to be considered for general use. In particular I did not do all relevant `null` or `0` tests. Also I did not attempt to support proper tagging.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer! "ImprovedAnnotationFlattening" method works well. I'm so sorry, in fact my product environment is itextsharp5.1.3. Considering the risk for upgrading to 5.5.13.1 directly, Is there correspond solution for it in version5.1.3? @mkl

Comment: Have you tried that code in 5.1.3? I haven't tried but I didn't use anything conceptually new, so probably some minor changes suffice to make the code runable under 5.1.3.

Comment: Additionally, I have the same question about flattening Form and FreeText ,etc. I want to study itext systematically, some recommendation will be appreciated. @mkl

Comment: I have tried that code in itextsharp5.1.3(older than 5.5.13.1). But no PdfContentByte#AddFormXObj found ;-）

Comment: You may want to try replacing that call by the code [that method currently executes](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.cs#L3036). The ISO conformance check and the stuff in `if (IsTagged())` blocks are optional...

Comment: *"Additionally, I have the same question about flattening Form and FreeText ,etc."* - actually the method above does flatten all kinds of annotations, also freetext and form widgets. In contrast to full form flattening the code does not remove the internal form structure, though.  *"I want to study itext systematically"* - wouldn't the current iText 7 be more appropriate then? iText 5 is legacy.